# How to create more than 1 object in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create more than 1 `TextBox` in my application.

[image: Only create 1 textbox]

My code bellow only creates one `TextBox` because I create a global object.

My code to do this:

```
private Label ctrLabel = new Label();

public void btnAddCharacter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String LableName = "Lbl_";
    ctrLabel.Name = LableName;
    ctrLabel.Text = txtIDImg.Text;
    panel2.Controls.Add(ctrLabel);
}
```

If put `Label ctrLabel = new Label();` inside the event `btnAddCharacter_Click` it will be create multiple object.
But all control using `ctrLabel` will error because it doesn't know `ctrLabel`.
The problem is: in other control of Winform will be using and manipulation with this object.

So, I don't know when user click `text 1` or `text 2`, etc.. to apply a change to the corresponding with event like: `cbxFontSize_SelectedIndexChanged`, `cbxFont_TextChanged`, etc .....

My code like this:

```
private void cbxFontSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrLabel.Font = new Font(ctrLabel.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(cbxFontSize.SelectedItem),
        ctrLabel.Font.Style);
}

private void cbxFont_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ctrLabel.Font = new Font(cbxFont.Text, ctrLabel.Font.Size, ctrLabel.Font.Style);
}
```

and much other control will change a property of an object(TextBox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private Label SelectedLabel; //don't initialize here (also note the name change)

public void btnAddCharacter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do it here:
    var ctrLabel = new Label();
    ctrLabel.Name = "Lbl_";
    ctrLabel.Text = txtIDImg.Text;
    ctrLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

    // In each of these events, add a line at the very top that looks like this:
    //     var ctrLabel = sender as Label;
    ctrLabel.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(control_MouseEnter);
    ctrLabel.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(control_MouseLeave);
    ctrLabel.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseDown);
    ctrLabel.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseMove);
    ctrLabel.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(control_MouseUp);

    panel2.Controls.Add(ctrLabel);
}

// Somewhere (perhaps in the events above) you have code that decides
// which control is selected. Now, instead of `ctrLabel`, you track this
// assigning to the `SelectedLabel` variable. Then the two methods below
// can look like this:
private void cbxFontSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedLabel == null) return;
    SelectedLabel.Font = new Font(ctrLabel.Font.FontFamily, Convert.ToInt32(cbxFontSize.SelectedItem),
        SelectedLabel.Font.Style);
}
private void cbxFont_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SelectedLabel == null) return;
    SelectedLabel.Font = new Font(cbxFont.Text, SelectedLabel.Font.Size, SelectedLabel.Font.Style);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed all. Your answer is useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell exactly what you are trying to do here, but if you want to manage multiple `Labels` that are created dynamically, you should maintain them using a list. I.E. like below (not tested code)

```
List<Label> activeLabels = new List<Label>();

private void CreateLabel() {
    Label ctrLabel = new Label();
    String LableName = "Lbl_" + activeLabels.Count();
    ctrLabel.Name = LableName;
    ctrLabel.Text = txtIDImg.Text;
    panel2.Controls.Add(ctrLabel);
    activeLabels.Add(ctrLabel);
}

private Label GetLabel(int index) {
    if (index > 0 && index < activeLabels.Count())
        return activeLabels[index];

    return null;
}
```